# Sharing a virtual screen from OS X to Windows

Tags: windows, vnc, osx-el-capitan, virtual-desktop, screen-sharing

I need to work on my MacBook Pro (El Capitan) while running an app which is always in fullscreen and blocks switching between spaces. However, when there is another screen available, the app only captures one screen, and the other can be used normally.

My Windows PC has two screens, both connected via DVI. I use PC's second screen almost exclusively for VNC client coming from a Raspberry Pi located on the other side of the house. On Raspberry Pi, setting up vnc server was very simple using `tightvncserver`, and I can generate new virtual screens with ease like so:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -dpi 96
```

At the moment, I don't need to use the screen for Raspberry Pi, so I wanted to use the screen as a second display for Mac through VNC. OS X already has Screen Sharing, but as I understand OS X (since Mountain Lion?) doesn't allow a separate screen for a VNC for a single user. TightVNC doesn't yet support OS X, so I looked for VNC server options on Google and through Homebrew, but I couldn't find a free solution which offers this feature.

Is there a way for my Mac to share a virtual screen with my PC so that I'm logged in as the same user on both screens, but so that they are detected as separate displays?

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://code.google.com/archive/p/ioproxyvideofamily/wikis/UsageAndInstallation.wiki on Lion.

Will try https://github.com/andreacremaschi/Syphon-virtual-screen/releases soon.

I personally use this with Teamviewer. But anything that can share a screen should work. See github.com/hverr/Satellite/blob/master/README.md